# Checkerboard with python

Tags: python

My task is to create a checkerboard in the form of a '*' symbol.  When writing the algorithm, I screwed up, and I don't understand where the algorithm malfunction is, how can I fix it?

```
n = int(input())
x = np.zeros((n,n), dtype=str)

x[1::2, ::2]='*'
x[::2,1::2]='*'

for i in range(n):
    for j in range(n):
        print(x[i][j], end=" ")
    print()
```

Output must be like:

```
* * * *
 * * * *
* * * *
 * * * *
* * * *
 * * * *
* * * *
 * * * *
```

Comment: Two problems: the non-asterisk elements of your array are empty strings, rather than spaces, so the columns won't line up.  Initialize it to spaces: `x[:, :] = ' '`.  Second, you're adding a space when printing the elements, to match your desired output you'd need to use `end=""`.

Comment: Updated
```
x[1::2,1::2]='*'
x[::2, ::2]='*'
```

Thanks to this I moved positions of my "*" symbols more correctly, but zeros appeared

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
n = int(input())
x = '* '

y = 1
for i in range(2*n):
    print(x[::y]*n)
    y *= -1
```

Output: Given `n == 4`

```
* * * *
 * * * *
* * * *
 * * * *
* * * *
 * * * *
* * * *
 * * * *
```